# How can I retrieve parameters from the path?

Tags: 8

I have a path

```
 /step/4?guide=6
```

How can I get parameters 'guide' and '6'in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

If this is Drupal 8, you can simply do:

```
$foo = \Drupal::request()->get('guide');
```

Comment: Please vote and accept if this is all you needed.